# Interpretation/ explanation for NA values produced by cox.zph

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I have set up several Cox proportional hazards models in R, and am using `cox.zph` from the `survival` package to test the proportional hazards assumption. Mostly this works well.

However, in a couple of cases running `cox.zph(model)` returns `NA` values for all covariates:

```
                   chisq df  p
variable_of_interest  NA  1 NA
GLOBAL                NA  1 NA
```

How should I interpret this? What could explain it?

**More details**

- Example model set-up: `coxph(Surv(age_entry, age_exit, event_status) ~ strata(sex) + variable_of_interest, my_data)` (simplified from original but still recreates the problem)
- This doesn't seem to depend on the adjustment variable(s) - while the example shown above is continuous, I also get `NA` values with a categorical variable there and when adjusting for several variables.
- If I adjust for, rather than stratify by, sex I no longer get `NA` values.
- If I change the model to `coxph(Surv(time_on_study, event_status) ~ strata(sex) + variable_of_interest, my_data)` I no longer get `NA` values.
- If I use only using particular subsets of the data, I sometimes no longer get `NA` values (but it doesn't seem quite as simple as a single problem row).
- The models are in epidemiologic data with 50,000 - 90,000 rows and ~1,500 events.
- I'm not familiar with all the aspects of the full `cox.zph` object, but with the models which output `NA` values, `y` seems to be entirely `NaN`, `var` is `NaN`, but everything else looks ok.

**Edits to the question** (Thanks to suggestions from @EdM)

- Running `residuals()`, the martingale and deviance residuals look ok (as far as I can tell) but the Schoenfeld and score residuals are all `NaN`. .
- No warnings are produced when I run the Cox models.
- The method for ties is the default, that is, `efron` (and changing it still results in `NA` values).
- Example `vcov`:

```
# Stratified model
                     variable_of_interest
variable_of_interest         0.0002427823

# Adjusted model 
                          sexMale variable_of_interest
sexMale               0.0030241365        -0.0001692652
variable_of_interest -0.0001692652         0.0002428107
```

- Example `summary`:

```
# Stratified model 
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(age_entry, age_exit, event) ~ 
    strata(sex) + variable_of_interest, data = my_data)
 n= 87498, number of events= 1393 

                         coef exp(coef) se(coef)    z Pr(>|z|)
variable_of_interest 0.009974  1.010024 0.015581 0.64    0.522

                     exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
variable_of_interest      1.01     0.9901    0.9796     1.041

Concordance= 0.513  (se = 0.009 )
Likelihood ratio test= 0.41  on 1 df,   p=0.5
Wald test            = 0.41  on 1 df,   p=0.5
Score (logrank) test = 0.41  on 1 df,   p=0.5


# Adjusted model 
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(age_entry, age_exit, event) ~ 
    sex + variable_of_interest, data = my_data)
  n= 87498, number of events= 1393 

                        coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)  
sexMale              0.13680   1.14660  0.05499 2.488   0.0129 *
variable_of_interest 0.01050   1.01055  0.01558 0.674   0.5005  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                     exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
sexMale                  1.147     0.8721    1.0294     1.277
variable_of_interest     1.011     0.9896    0.9802     1.042

Concordance= 0.522  (se = 0.008 )
Likelihood ratio test= 7.56  on 2 df,   p=0.02
Wald test            = 7.6  on 2 df,   p=0.02
Score (logrank) test = 7.61  on 2 df,   p=0.02
```

- I get the same result if I run with `x = TRUE`.
- Adding interaction terms with the strata was interesting. For the continuous variable above, `cox.zph` still produced `NA` values.  But with a different continuous variable, which also produced `NA` values in the original setup, in the model with the interaction term the residuals were fine and `cox.zph` produced results.
- This led me to try out more different variables in the model. With the model above (`coxph(Surv(age_entry, age_exit, event_status) ~ strata(sex) + variable_of_interest, my_data)`) most variables produced `NA` values in `cox.zph`. But 6/60 produced results in `cox.zph`. All of these were continuous variables. In the model with the interaction term, `coxph(Surv(age_entry, age_exit, event_status) ~ strata(sex) + variable_of_interest + variable_of_interest*strata(sex), my_data)`, 14/60  produced results. This included some categorical variables.

**Further Edit**

- I was using `survival 3.2-7`. I updated to `survival 3.2-11`, and now it seems to work as expected (no `NA` values).

Comment: Your `variable_of_interest` seems to be 4-level categorical. Please edit your question to show the breakdown of that variable by sex in the overall data set and in a subset for which the model worked. Also, please triple check that all `age_exit` values are greater than the corresponding `age_entry` values. If `cox.zph()` can't get the scaled Schoenfeld residuals from the model (`y` values in the `cox.zph` object), there might be something wrong with the original model, too. Please summarize in your question the results of `residuals()` on the original `coxph` object for each residual type.

Comment: Thanks @EdM!
I added some details answering your questions above. Please let me know if further detail would be helpful, especially on the summary of the residuals.
I have also checked that `age_exit` are all greater than `age_entry`. 
While as noted above particular variable doesn't seem to be driving it, the breakdown was: L1: 21611 F, 15380 M; L2 1404 F,   2191 M; L3: 6785 F, 7508 M; L4: 21082 F,11537 M
On whether there is something wrong with the original model, that is also my worry! But, I haven't noticed anything obvious, and it gives reasonable results in the model summary.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the original `coxph` model (not `cox.zph` per se), please look at the following, and report results by editing the question. First, what are the (co)variance matrices of coefficient estimates for the sex-stratified model that fails and for the additive model that succeeds? (That's the `$var` component of the `coxph` object, or `vcov(object)`.) Second, see what happens if you model an interaction of your `variable_of_interest` with the strata: `variable_of_interest * strata(sex)`. Work with the continuous covariate if that's simpler than the 4-level categorical.

Comment: Also, when you call `coxph()`, do you set `x=TRUE` to keep a copy of the predictor matrix in the returned object? Probably doesn't matter, but I'm just trying to think of things that can go wrong. Another unlikely issue: are you calling `coxph()` with `ties="exact"`? You seem to accept the default `ties="efron"` in your call; `coxph()` won't return score or Schoenfeld residuals with `ties="exact"`.

Comment: One more thought: in your question, show the `summary()` output from the stratified `coxph` model that generates the problem and from the the additive `coxph` model that doesn't. If there were any warnings generated when you ran `coxph()` please show those in the question, also.

Comment: Thank you! All added above. It's interesting that it does seem to depend on which variables are in the model, which I hadn't realised before. Still not sure what's going on, though!

Comment: Interestingly it doesn't seem to be an issue any more if I update the version of `survival`, which is probably a resolution of sorts (if a bit unsatisfactory!)